# Negative current peak after voltage drop

Tags: dc-motor

I've got these two curves from a DC motor.
At the second measuring point you can see that the voltage dropped and at the same time, the current dropped to before it rises slowly until it arrives at the no-load current.

My question: Why does the current drop into the negative range before it arrives at (the new) no-load current?

My assumption is that it comes from the winding inductance but I can't express it in words (or equations).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A winding inductance will generate a voltage if the current changes, but just before point test nº 2, current is zero and cannot explain this negative values.
If you look after point nº 1, the current goes slow to zero, that means that motor has accelerated and reached a stable speed, proportional to voltage 50 V. At point 2, voltage is reduced to 30 V, so speed will also decrease accordingly to a lower value. New speed is reached as current goes to zero value, mechanical inertia will need a negative torque (also negative current) to decelerate the motor.